# How to extract zip files in a MemoryStream List?

Tags: c#

I have a method that has a ZipArchive as parameter, and I have to return a List with the entries of the zip. How can I do it?

This is what I have:

```
    public static List<MemoryStream> ExtractZip(ZipArchive zip)
    {
        List<MemoryStream> memoryStreamList = new List<MemoryStream>();          
        foreach (var entry in zip.Entries)
        {
            Stream stream = entry.Open();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            stream.CopyTo(ms);
            memoryStreamList.Add(ms);
        }

        return memoryStreamList;
    }
```

Comment: The `ZipArchive` class already contains an [Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries?view=netframework-4.8) property. What exactly are you looking to return from your method?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to unzip a ZipArchive in memory, and I want to store all the entries in a List<MemoryStream> .

Comment: And what doesn't work about what you have? It looks ok, other than maybe you want to put `ms.Position = 0` after the CopyTo so the caller doesn't have to do it.